# Substring: No matching signature for function SUBSTR for argument types INT64, INT64, INT64

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, substring

I am using the code below to try and aggregate the quarterly wages for individuals from 2010Q1-2020Q4. I have used this code before in other SQL programs though not in Google Big Query. From the code it seems as though I need to change the wg.yrqtr to a String format, however, due to me being new to Big Query, I do not know how to do this properly

```
with TECH as (
SELECT
  certificate.MASTER_PERSON_INDEX tech_mpi,
  certificate.U_COMP_CIP as g_cip,
  case when u_req_hrs <300 then '1A'
       when u_req_hrs >= 300 and u_req_hrs < 900 then '1B'
       when u_req_hrs >= 900 then '2'
       else null end ipeds,
  --u_comp_age, 
  u_issue_date g_date,
  GENDER, U_ETH_RACE_U G_ETHNIC_U, U_ETHNIC_H, U_RACE_A G_ETHNIC_A, U_RACE_B G_ETHNIC_B, U_RACE_I G_ETHNIC_I,
  U_RACE_MULTI, U_RACE_P, U_RACE_W
FROM 
  `STC.STC_CERTIFICATE_DI_DATA_TABLE` certificate
)
,
ws_data as (
SELECT
        MASTER_PERSON_INDEX AS mpi
        ,SUBSTR(wg.naics, 1, 3) AS NAICS_2
--        ,ncs_tb.TITLE AS NAICS_DESC
        ,SUBSTR(wg.yrqtr, 0,5) AS quarter
        ,wg.yrqtr
        ,wg.employer
        ,wg.wages
        ,SUBSTR(wg.yrqtr, 0,4) AS YEAR
    FROM
        (   SELECT
                *
            FROM
                `WS.WS_UI_WAGE_RECORDS_DI` wsui
            WHERE  -- Putting all the where statements possible here limits search on the DWS table, which is large
                wsui.MASTER_PERSON_INDEX IN (SELECT tech_mpi FROM tech)
                AND
                wsui.yrqtr IN (20101, 20102, 20103, 20104,
                        20111, 20112, 20113, 20114,
                        20121, 20122, 20123, 20124,
                        20131, 20132, 20133, 20134,
                        20141, 20142, 20143, 20144,
                        20151, 20152, 20153, 20154,
                        20161, 20162, 20163, 20164,
                        20171, 20172, 20173, 20174,
                        20181, 20182, 20183, 20184,
                        20191, 20192, 20193, 20194,
                        20201, 20202, 20203, 20204)
                                             )wg

        -----grab the naics description
--        LEFT JOIN UDRC_NAICS ncs_tb
--            ON ncs_tb.CODE = SUBSTR(wg.NAICS, 1,3)

    ),

    ws_agg AS (
    SELECT
        mpi
        ,STATS_MODE(NAICS_2) AS NAICS_2 
     --   ,STATS_MODE(NAICS_DESC) AS NAICS_DESC
        ,quarter
        ,SUM(wages) AS wages_quart
    FROM
        ws_data

    GROUP BY
        mpi, quarter
    ),

    ws_annot AS (
    SELECT
        dagg.*
        ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY dagg.mpi, dagg.wages_quart ORDER BY dagg.wages_quart  DESC)AS rn
    FROM
        dws_agg dagg
    )


select distinct
  tech_mpi,
  g_cip,
  ipeds,
u_issue_date g_date,
  GENDER, U_ETH_RACE_U G_ETHNIC_U, U_ETHNIC_H, U_RACE_A G_ETHNIC_A,
  U_RACE_B G_ETHNIC_B, U_RACE_I G_ETHNIC_I,
  U_RACE_MULTI, U_RACE_P, U_RACE_W,


  mpi,
  NAICS_2,
  NAICS_DESC,
  quarter,
  wg.yrqtr,
  wg.employer,
  wg.wages,
  YEAR

from 
  tech l

  left join
  ws_annot
  on
  l.tech_mpi = ws_annot.mpi
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the type, refer here : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions

In your case :

```
CAST(wg.yrqtr AS STRING)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! The only problem I am facing now is the "STATS_MODE(NAICS_2) AS NAICS_2. It states that the function is not found. Is there another way of getting the mode for this item?